# How to backup and restore all installed snap packages?

Tags: backup, snap

I need to reinstall my Ubuntu 18.04 and I want to backup and restore all installed snap packages including all installation settings.

With `snap list` I get the list of installed packages. However, the list is not in a suitable format for reinstalling all the packages. I need something like `apt-clone` that would work for snap packages the same way it works for apt installed packages.

Answer (score 8):

You can save installed packages using following code

```
snap save
```

And then all the installed packeges will be zipped with data to /var/lib/snapd/snapshots/

For more information go here https://snapcraft.io/blog/how-to-create-snapshots-of-your-snaps