# Does Snap take up more space in a backup when I use Rsync?

Tags: server, snap, 22.04, rsync, squashfs

I am using rsync to backup my Ubuntu 22.04 server running on an SD Card in a Raspberry Pi. I run the backup when Ubuntu is also running with this command:

> ```
> > rsync -aDH --partial --numeric-ids --delete --force --exclude "${MNTPATH}" --exclude '/dev' --exclude '/lost+found' --exclude '/media' --exclude '/mnt' \
> > --exclude '/proc' --exclude '/run' --exclude '/sys' --exclude '/tmp' --exclude '/var/swap' --exclude '/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules' \
> > --exclude '/var/lib/asterisk/astdb.sqlite3-journal' "${OPTIONS[@]}" / "${MNTPATH}/"
> ```

So all (I think) of the directories whose content appears at runtime only are excluded from the backup... as well as the /media and /mnt directories.

HOWEVER... my resulting backup is always a lot bigger than I would expect. The backup is created using rsync on to an image file (using the `truncate` command) that is partitioned and formatted (boot partition as fat32 and root partition as ext4).

When I loopmount this image file and also take out the Ubuntu server sd card and mount them both separately in my laptop I get this:

The root partition on the backup image has been loop device mounted in my laptop running Manjaro.

```
[flex@flex~]$ sudo du -hs /media/writable/
4.8G    /media/writable/
```

The root partition on the SD Card containing the OS that the backup was made from with that SD Card removed from the Pi.

```
[flex@flex~]$ sudo du -hs /media/writable1/
3.3G    /media/writable1/
```

Why is the backup 1.5GB bigger than the original it was made from? The backup should be smaller because it excluded a lot of runtime directories from Ubuntu running on the sd card.

**More Debugging**
I ran this rsync command to double check if some mysterious extra files were being created on the destination that are not on the source or were the same files getting bigger when they were on the destination compared with them on the source:

```
sudo rsync -nrlpgoDv --delete --exclude-from='/home/ubuntu/exclude-list.txt' / /mnt/dst_root/

/home/ubuntu/exclude-list.txt
dev
lost+found
media/4TB1
mnt
proc
run
sys
tmp
```

But I don’t see any big differences between the source and destination in terms of numbers of files or the size they occupy in source vs destination.

**Snap is installed**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/snap$ ls -l
total 20
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  548 Apr 19 11:11 README
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 21 21:30 bin
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May 27 17:19 core20
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May 21 21:30 lxd
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May 27 17:18 snapd

ubuntu@ubuntu:/snap$ snap list
Name    Version        Rev    Tracking       Publisher   Notes
core20  20220512       1498   latest/stable  canonical*  base
lxd     5.0.0-b0287c1  22927  5.0/stable/…   canonical*  -
snapd   2.55.5         15909  latest/stable  canonical*  snapd

ubuntu@ubuntu:/snap$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           379M  4.7M  375M   2% /run
/dev/mmcblk0p2   30G  3.7G   25G  13% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M  148M  105M  59% /boot/firmware
/dev/sda1       3.6T  1.3T  2.2T  37% /media/4TB1

ubuntu@ubuntu:/snap$ sudo losetup -a
/dev/loop1: [45826]:1392 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_1498.snap)
/dev/loop4: [45826]:7068 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_15541.snap)
/dev/loop2: [45826]:77516 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/lxd_22915.snap)
/dev/loop0: [45826]:7407 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_1437.snap)
/dev/loop5: [45826]:7773 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_15909.snap)
/dev/loop3: [45826]:7426 (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/lxd_22927.snap)
```

**My Theory**
Is this because of snap? Maybe because when I rsync from Ubuntu I copy snap installation and data files and settings which exist in squashfs file system which is compressed and so on the destination they take up less space?

In case my theory is correct which Snap related things can I exclude from my backup if any? I read somewhere that it may not be safe to exclude /snap because it could have application related settings in there.

Any advice much appreciated.

Cheers,

flex

Comment: Exclude snaps from your backup.  Instead back up a list of installed snaps and reinstall them on a restore.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but a little more explanation and justification for your advice would be really helpful.

Comment: snaps are read-only, they don't change and should not be restored directly from a backup.  They are managed by snapd, and their contents are in readonly loop mounts which are not changeable.  Therefore, there's no benefits to backing up readonly images which can simply be reinstalled instead.  That will save a **lot** of space in your backups.

Answer (score 0):

After some further investigation and helpful responses from this [Raspberry Pi thread](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2007490#p2007286) and this [snapcraft.io thread](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/rsyncing-the-snap-directory-backup-is-bigger-than-source/30263) I have an answer.

Snap applications are stored in squashfs image files. They are located in `/var/lib/snapd/` and mounted in `/snap` at OS boot up. I run rsync on the entire root directory of a running Ubuntu OS and have not been excluding anything snap related from the backup.

So my backup image file contains a copy of the snap applications that reside in `/var/lib/snapd/` as well as the same applications mounted in `/snap`. Writable system data of snaps lives underneath `/var/snap`, writable user data in `~/snap` so there is no reason to backup anything in `/snap`. This is why my backup contains more data that it needed to.

Technically speaking the data in my backup image was not taking up more space as it did on the source sd card which is what I originally thought. My confusion was due to the way I was running the `du command`. I was taking the SD Card out of the Pi and mounting it in my laptop then running the command on the sd card root partition. I should have run the command while the OS was running on the SD Card. When the OS is not running the contents of `/snap` is practically empty.

With the SD Card OUT of the Pi and it's root partition mounted at `/media/writable1`

```
[flex@flex~]$ sudo du -hs /media/writable1/
3.3G    /media/writable1/
```

With the SD Card attached to the Pi and Ubuntu running from that card...

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo du -hs /
du: cannot access '/proc/1118/task/1118/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/1118/task/1118/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/1118/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/1118/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
4.7G    /
```

Of course there are other ways to [backup snaps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124251/how-to-backup-and-restore-all-installed-snap-packages) and [backup snap application settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246396/how-to-properly-backup-snap-settings). But in my case where I do an entire system backup it is safe to omit the `/snap` directory from that backup and the rest of the snap related data will not take any more space on the destination as it does on the source.